# Add a column to a data frame based on a condition

Tags: r

Suppose I have 2 data frames:

```
library(tidyverse)
quaters <- tibble(
  quarter = c("Q1", "Q2","Q3", "Q4"),
  start_date = as.Date(c("2020-4-20", "2020-7-21", "2020-10-22", "2021-1-22")),
  end_date = as.Date(c("2020-7-20", "2020-10-21", "2021-1-22", "2021-4-22"))
)

test_data <- tibble(city =c("Paris", "London", "Rome"),
     date = as.Date(c("2020-6-25", "2020-9-12", "2020-10-11")))
```

I want to define a quarter for each date in "test_data" based on "quarters" and add it as a column to "test_data". Thus, Paris should be Q1, London - Q2, Rome - Q3. Can I do it just with `mutate` or smth like that? I can do it with a function and sapply but it takes a lot of time for R to calculate large datasets and I'm sure this is not the best solution (the `quarter` function doesn't help because I want to define start and end dates of a quarter manually).
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a non-equi join from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test_data)[as.data.table(quaters), 
    quarter := i.quarter,on = .(date >= start_date, date <= end_date)]
```

-output

```
test_data
#     city       date quarter    
#1:  Paris 2020-06-25      Q1
#2: London 2020-09-12      Q2
#3:   Rome 2020-10-11      Q2
```

Comment: Thanks! I used it on data tables and all is fine, but if my data is `data.frame` it doesn't work. What can I do to fix it? Just tried to use as.data.table and  something went wrong with encoding

Comment: @SarkansSatans You can convert to data.table with `setDT` and from data.table -> data.frame with `setDF`

Comment: thanks, just wrote setDF instead of setDT. Is there another way to do it with the dplyr package? If it's not I will have to deal with new data.frame's syntax and I've never used it before, seems like I have to read all the basics of "data.frame"

Comment: @SarkansSatans if you use `setDF`, it converts to `data.frame` and the code wont work because it is a data.table syntax.  You need `setDT`